# How can I show this implication for $\frac x{xy+x+1} + \frac y{yz+y+1} +\frac z{zx+z+1} = 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$(xy+x\ne -1 \land yz+y\ne-1 \land zx+z\ne -1 \land xyz=1)\\
\implies \frac x{xy+x+1} + \frac y{yz+y+1} +\frac z{zx+z+1} = 1$$

I tried finding each variables value using $xyz=1$ $(ex.x=1/yz)$ , and then replacing them but didnt really get anything. Then i tried writing the $1$s as $xyz$ and i could simplify some of them but still nothing. Thank you in advance

Comment: By "=!" you intend $\neq$?

Comment: What does $=!$ mean?

Comment: Use "\neq" for not equal to. See more pointers here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: When working with sums of fractions, trick #1 is .... to add them, by giving them a common denominator and adding the numerators. I know it will be a mess. Nonetheless, did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac x{xy+x+1} + \frac y{yz+y+1} +\frac z{zx+z+1}\\
\stackrel{z=\frac1{xy}}=\frac x{xy+x+1}+\frac{xy}{xy+x+1}+\frac{1}{xy+x+1}.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah i figured it out now , thank you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!